# Explaining the first step in the proof of Steinhaus Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Theorem. Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable with positive measure. Then there exists positive $\epsilon$ such that $(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subset E - E$, where $E - E := \{e_1 - e_2 : e_1, e_2 \in E\}$.

Start of the proof:

Let $E_n := E \cap [-n, n]$. Then $E_n $ has a finite measure for all $n$ and $\lim(m(E_n))= m(E)>0$. Thus $m(E_N) > 0$ for sufficiently large $N$ and we assume that $m(E)<\infty$.

My question is, is it enough to assume that $m(E) < \infty$? What if $m(E)=\infty$, say $E=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The paragraph is meant to ***reduce*** the problem to a bounded set with positive and finite measure. If $m(E)=\infty$ or $E$ is unbounded, you then replace it with $E_N$ and continue from there.  Note that since $E_N\subseteq E$, $E_N -E_N \subseteq E-E$.

Comment: But is it no longer necessary to include in the proof that if $m(E) = \infty$, replace it with $E_N$ and show that $E_N - E_N \subseteq E-E$?

Comment: Think of it this way:  1. You show that any set with positive measure (finite or not) contains a bounded set with positive measure. 2. Then all you need to do is to prove the theorem for sets which are bounded and with positive measure.